# Referring to manifest.json while index.html is not inside root directory

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

I am trying create and register a manifest.json and service-worker.js file in order for our website to become a PWA.

The problem is that Chrome does not receive any manifest.json file and instead replies with `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`

Our app structure regarding the mentioned files looks like this (index.html nested inside the `public/` directory):

```
public/
    - index.html
    - favicon.ico
manifest.json
...
```

Inside index.html I am referring to the manifest.json by entering its path relative to the root directory:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
```

`mainfest.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Who Knows - Die Quizapp zum Testen Deiner Menschenkenntnis",
    "short_name": "Who Knows",
    "description": "Testen Sie Ihre Menschenkenntnis",
    "lang": "de",
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#BF0436",
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "images-ressources/icon-192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "images-ressources/icon-256x256.png",
        "sizes": "256x256",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "images-ressources/icon-384x384.png",
        "sizes": "384x384",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "images-ressources/icon-512x512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ]
}
```

When I move the `manifest.json` file into `public/` it all works perfectly fine (except for the icon paths). That's why I guess I have a path problem. I would rather not change the directory structure due to it being a project in which several other people work.

Comment: My best guess would be that all your files should be in `public` and the icons don't work I because you have a typo (double s) in `images-ressources`.

Comment: Are you sure your manifest file is actually served by your web server ? Can you fetch it manually from your browser ? Also, make sure the `start_url` is inside the `scope` otherwise it cannot find the starting page.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is https://yourdomain/public/
and your service worker and manifest are at the root, not /public, then yes you have issues. If public is mapped as your default folder in your web server then place your manifest and service worker in the /public folder.